# Calling a function on React Element before the Component did mount

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to use an React Component as a object to make some calculation based on other components **before I render / mount them**. I have a working solution but I find the part `a.type.prototype.calculate.bind(a)()` quite dirty.

Here's my current way ([also on JSBin](https://jsbin.com/kahuwun/edit?js,console,output)):

```js
class ChildComponent extends React.Component {
  calculate() {
    return this.props.a + this.props.b;
  }

  render() {
    return <span>{this.props.a + this.props.b} </span>
  }
}

class ParentComponent extends React.Component {
  render() {
    var children = [
      <ChildComponent a={2} b={3} key="1" />,
      <ChildComponent a={1} b={2} key="2" />
    ];    
    var children_sorted = children.slice();
    
    children_sorted.sort((a,b) => {
      return a.type.prototype.calculate.bind(a)()
      - b.type.prototype.calculate.bind(b)()
    });

    return (
      <h1>Children {children} -> {children_sorted}</h1>      
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <ParentComponent/>,
  document.getElementById('react_example')
);
```

```html
<div id="react_example"></div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.4.2/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.4.2/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Does somebody have a better way to achieve that?

Comment: FYI for next time, you can put your full, runnable example **here, on-site** using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button). Stack Snippets support React, including JSX; [here's how to do one](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338537/).

Comment: In my used scenario I will have inherited components similar to this: https://jsbin.com/xezibiz/edit?js,console,output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way that comes to mind is to make `calculate` static:

```
static calculate({a, b}) {
  return a + b;
}
```

...and pass `props` into it:

```
children_sorted.sort((a,b) => a.type.calculate(a.props) - b.type.calculate(b.props));
```

Live Example:

```js
class ChildComponent extends React.Component {
  static calculate({a, b}) {
    return a + b;
  }

  render() {
    return <span>{this.props.a + this.props.b} </span>
  }
}

class ParentComponent extends React.Component {
  render() {
    var children = [
      <ChildComponent a={2} b={3} key="1" />,
      <ChildComponent a={1} b={2} key="2" />
    ];    
    var children_sorted = children.slice();

    children_sorted.sort((a,b) => a.type.calculate(a.props) - b.type.calculate(b.props));

    return (
      <h1>Children {children} -> {children_sorted}</h1>      
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <ParentComponent/>,
  document.getElementById('react_example')
);
```

```html
<div id="react_example"></div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.4.2/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.4.2/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

If the children need to make the same calculation, they can use `calculate` as well, via `ChildComponent.calculate(this.props)` (which will always use the version of `calculate` on `ChildComponent` or `this.constructor.calculate(this.props)` which will use the version of `calculate` on the constructor that created the instance (under normal circumstances). If it's a subclass of `ChildComponent` and doesn't need its own `calculate`, it will inherit `ChildComponent`'s (yes, static methods are inherited with `class` syntax).

Comment: Okay, that is better, **thank you**! I wait if there is another idea to flag the answer.

Comment: @AndreasRichter - No worries. I expanded the last paragraph since you mentioned having subclassed components. (Just FWIW, the React team recommend aggregation and containment over inheritance, but pehaps you have a use case for inheritance instead.)

Answer (score 1):

Is there a reason for using a component for the calculations?

This can be a simple function. This example could probably be simplified further....

```js
class ParentComponent extends React.Component {
  calculate = (a, b) => a + b;

  render() {
    const children = [this.calculate(2, 3), this.calculate(1, 2)];
    const children_sorted = [this.calculate(2, 3), this.calculate(1, 2)].sort();

    return (
      <h1>
        {children.map((x) => x)} => {children_sorted.map((x) => x)}
      </h1>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<ParentComponent />, document.getElementById('react_example'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.js"></script>

<div id="react_example"></div>
```

Comment: Yes there is a reason, the Child Component comes with own view logic, props and states in my real application.